# Add item to JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object that i'm try to add to.  Below is the code i'm  using (the commented out bit also didn't seem to do what I need) :

```
$('#classes tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');        
    if ($.isEmptyObject(jsonData)) {            
        jsonData = {
            "row": [
            {
                "OpenClosed": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(1)').text(),
                "Section": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(2)').text(),
                "CRN": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(3)').text(),
                "CreditHours": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(4)').text()
            }

            ]
        };
    }

    else if (!$.isEmptyObject(jsonData)) {                        
        jsonData['row'] = {
                "OpenClosed": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(1)').text(),
                "Section": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(2)').text(),
                "CRN": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(3)').text(),
                "CreditHours": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(4)').text()
        };            
        //jsonData.row.push = {
        //    "OpenClosed": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(1)').text(),
        //    "Section": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(2)').text(),
        //    "CRN": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(3)').text(),
        //    "CreditHours": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(4)').text()
        //};                        
    }        
});
```

The user clicks on a row and I need it to add that row where `class=selected` to the JSON object.  Currently it appears to append (in Chrome Dev Tools) instead of add a new row.  When I selected two rows I end up with this `CRN: "8063780639"` where the CRNs should be 80637 and 80639 on separate rows.  I need each click to add a `row` like row[0], row[1], row[2] etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

push is not a property, it is a method. So you have to call it using `(...)`

```
jsonData.row.push({
        "OpenClosed": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(1)').text(),
        "Section": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(2)').text(),
        "CRN": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(3)').text(),
        "CreditHours": $('tr.selected td:nth-child(4)').text()
    });
```

Comment: Damn, got it before me :D Exactly the same as what I was going to write.

Comment: This is what I get when I use push correctly [http://imgur.com/ITAmazn](http://imgur.com/ITAmazn)

Comment: The result shows me that you still used `jsonData.row.push = ...` instead of `jsonData.row.push(...)`